# Two list sorting one by ascending other by descending but constrained

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

Got very basic question:
I need to implement this in C#.
I have got two list Say List1 and List2

List1   23,34,45,12,34,34,67,100,34

List2    0.1,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.15,0.17,0.91,0.81,0.3

As you can see there is duplication of data points in list1 (34 in this case)
I have to sort List1 in descending order constrained on List2 such that if there is duplicated entry in List1(34) then take the highest corresponding value from List2 (here 34 has got 0.3,0.3,0.17 and 0.15)
So output should be first 34 corresponding to 0.3, then to 0.3 then to 0.17 and then to 0.15

List1   100,67,45,34,34,34,34,23,12

List2    0.81,0.91,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.17,0.15,0.1,0.2

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: From what you've written I cannot really make out what exactly list1 and what list2 is. Also I don't quite understand what the expected outcome is. Can you give an example that is a bit clearer? thanks.

Comment: Do you already have these lists in a specific structure (eg a List<int> and List<double>) do you have any code already and do you have any thoughts on how to do it? It is generally nice to show you have made a stab at the problem so we know where to help more precisely...

Comment: Thank you Chris for making the post clear :)

Comment: This would probably be a pretty simple LINQ query - are you allowed to use LINQ for this homework assignment?

Answer (score 8):

That looks like:

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (x, y) => new { x, y })
                  .OrderByDescending(z => z.x)
                  .ThenByDescending(z => z.y);
```

The result will be a sequence of an anonymous type where `x` corresponds to a value in `list1`, `y` corresponds to a value in `list2`, and the whole thing is sorted in a descending order on `x` then `y`.